# Pilot Signal Overhead

Tags: ofdm, channel, channel-estimation

I have a doubt regarding Pilot signals such as CSI-RS in NR.

Using a large number of CSI-RS affects Datarate significantly?

or it is negligible?

Because I wonder it is meaningful that optimize the number of CSI-RS.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Obviously a pilot impacts bitrate, but you could trade off against poorly quality signal reception. There's a way to optimize pilot rate but it's dependent upon the environment.

Comment: To answer your questions: Yes. It depends. It is. You may want to check these papers [(Ostman et al., 2017)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.06387.pdf) and [(Ferrante et al., 2018)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.10552.pdf).

Comment: @FourierFlux Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @AlexTP Thank you! I will take a look at the papers.

Comment: Basically you need to account for how fast the channel changes. From what I remember if you viewed it as a type of gaussian process there's a way to compute the optimal update rate but I do not remember.